# Problemas ao passar uma lista de objetos para outra lista

Tags: c#, angularjs

Preciso passar, uma lista de objetos de uma tabela, para outra lista de objetos de outra tabela, já consegui buscar as informações, porem não consigo salvá-las.

Ex: 
 Tenho uma tabela de pessoas, no caso tenho os campos: Nome, Idade, Telefone, CPF, Endereço, fk_estado

E na outra tabela que faz ligação com a de pessoas a de estado, sendo que uma pessoa pode ter mais de um estado, ou seja, relacionamento muitos para muitos, porém na hora de salvar, como posso fazer pra salvar esta lista?

Comment: Como esta seu modelo? e como você esta tentando salvar?

Comment: Mostre o código! a parte que interessa!

Comment: Clique em [edit] e coloque o código.

Comment: Poderia adicionar a parte do seu código que está a trabalhar? Caso esteja trabalhando em código protegido sugiro que crie um código de exemplo para exemplificar melhor a sua dúvida

Comment: Acredito que o problema tem mais a ver com SQL Server do que com C# ou angularjs, mesmo que você utilize essas duas últimas tecnologias em sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar algo da seguinte forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E adicionar sua lista assim.

```
-- Sua primeira pessoa
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Pessoas]([Nome],[Idade],[Telefone],[CPF])
     VALUES('Carlos',21,'1122223333','345.322.234-54')
GO


 -- Sua lista de Estados 
 -- após você grava seu usuario você tem que fazer um loop para salvar cada estado da pessoa,
 -- caso isso esteja dentro de alguma aplicação 

 declare @IdPessoa int = @@IDENTITY;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Estados]([IdPessoa] ,[Descricao]) VALUES
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 1'),  -- Aqui onde ficar a intereção do seu insert veja que o IdUsuario é sempre o mesmo
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 2'),  -- ou seja para pessoa você pode ter mais de um estado. 
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 3'),  
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 4'),  
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 5'),  
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 6'),  
 (@IdPessoa,'Estado 7')


 select * from Pessoas P
 join Estados E
 on E.IdPessoa = P.IdPessoa

IdPessoa    Nome    Idade   Telefone    CPF IdEstado    IdPessoa    Descricao
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  1   2   Estado 1
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  2   2   Estado 2
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  3   2   Estado 3
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  4   2   Estado 4
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  5   2   Estado 5
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  6   2   Estado 6
2   Carlos  21  1122223333  345.322.234-54  7   2   Estado 7
```

Comment: Lembrando que isso seria uma solução feita em SQL SERVER.